# Remove All Features from Vector Layer in OpenLayers 3

Tags: openlayers

Looking at the OpenLayers 3 [ol.source.Vector docs](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.0.0/apidoc/ol.source.Vector.html#removeFeature), I can see that there exists a method `ol.Vector.removeFeature(feature)`.

Does this mean the best way to remove all the features from a vector layer would be something like this...?

```
var iter = layer.getFeatures().values();
while (!(entry = iter.next()).done) { 
    layer.removeFeature(entry.value); 
}
```

Or is there better way?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Ok let's try again.

If you look closer at the docs you will see that `ol.source.Vector` has a `clear` method that you can use to remove all the features from the source.

See http://openlayers.org/en/v3.0.0/apidoc/ol.source.Vector.html#clear

This is how you will use that method:

```js
vectorSource.clear()
```

Comment: Ah! Must have scrolled by that one. Thanks @erilem!

Comment: I have been using .clear for removing features from the source but now I get an error: "Uncaught TypeError: Array.prototype.forEach called on null or undefined" it is a clear error; however, checking the source shows that the source already has objects in it and also is not undefined: >>console.info(source.getFeatures());>>[Bn, Bn] ;>>console.info(source); >>W {fa: false, da: undefined, jb: Gc, Hd: W, Ma: null…}... any idea why it spits such an error?